# scheduled task on centos server 

Tags: linux, batch-file, cron, centos, scheduled-tasks

I tried **now + time** on **centos**, but it didnt work perfectly for me.

I want my centos server to run a script within 10 mins exactly after 5 days whenever the server is started, either it is started @ 1pm or 5pm or 12 am or on the 7th day or 13th day i.e. recurring on server start after 5 days is over.

Can any one help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand your question... but did you already try with **at** command?

I mean something like this:

```
at now + 5 days < /path/to/yourscript.sh
```

Where yourscript.sh should have a loop waiting 10 minutes between each operation.

Comment: @matteomattie if i type that command @ 1200 hrs, **now** command will be operated at same time after 5 days, ie 1200 hrs, if i am not wrong. What if the server is shut at 1100hrs and started after 1300 hrs, will the script work

Comment: 5 days is 120 hours, not 1200 hours. You can add the **at** command in an init script (/etc/rc.local should work) so that each time the server starts, wait 5 days before execute your custom script.